# Multiple foreign key in java JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I want to persist an instance of Class2 in database. but when I send GET request to '/two', it reports exception `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id1" of relation "class2" violates not-null constraint Detail: Failing row contains (2, null, null, 1).`

what can I do to successfully persist a new instance of Class2. and is it possible to make PK the primary key of Class2 (PK is the primary key of Class1 and the foreign key of Class2, I want to make it the primary key of Class2)

Class1.java

```java
@Table
@Entity
@Data
@IdClass(PK.class)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Class1{

    @Id
    private int id1;

    @Id
    private int id2;

    private int one;

}
```

Class2.java

```
@Table
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Class2{

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "id1", referencedColumnName = "id1", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "id2", referencedColumnName = "id2", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Class1 class1;

    private int two;

}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class ForeignController {

    @Autowired
    Class1Repository repository1;

    @Autowired
    Class2Repository repository2;

    @GetMapping("/one")
    public void createone(int id1, int id2, int one){
        repository1.saveAndFlush(new Class1(id1, id2, one));
    }

    @GetMapping("/two")
    public void createtwo(int id1, int id2, int two, int id){
        Class1 class1 = repository1.getOne(new PK(id1, id2));
        repository2.saveAndFlush(new Class2(id, class1, two));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how you do composite keys in jpa.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of @IdClass, use @EmbeddedId

```
@Table
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Class1{

    @EmbeddedId
    private PK pk;

    private int one;

}
```

```
public class Class2{

    @EmbeddedId
    private PK pk;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    private Class1 class1;

    private int two;

}
```